# PDF link showing only one page inside iFrame (iPad only)

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, iframe, fancybox

So I am developer of an reporting system which works in iPad. But now we have encountered a problem with pdf file links.

So in our system we have virtual tour where are hotspots which open websites in iFrame. That is working fine. But some websites have pdf links which when opened inside iFrame will load only the first page.

For iFrame we use simply Fancybox system. And we are not able to edit the websites. So we should make the fancybox iframe combo able to adjust to opening pdfs. If the link is opened in a new tab it works just fine. And that would also be solution for as. But how can I set links inside iFrame to open to a new tab? If I cannot touch the page itself just the fancybox.

We have latest version of fancybox 2.1.5 and here is my config file:

```
function openfancybox(url) {
    var scale = 0.8;
    var width = $('body').width() * scale;
    var height = $('body').height() * scale;

    $.fancybox({
        'href' : url,
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'preload' : 'false',
        'scrolling' : 'auto',
        'height' : '3000',
        'width' : '800'
    });
}
```

Links for websites are inside xml file. From where they are opened with command openfancybox. But problem is then links inside that website which we open. Any ideas are welcome. We have also considered abandoning fancybox for better alternative but haven't found one which would work inside virtual tour.

Thanks for helping!

EDIT: Forgot to mention. Everything works fine in Desktop. So problem exists only in iPads.

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Comment: We never found true solution to this. But we managed by expanding the height of the Fancybox. When it is extended to be big enough, pdfs will work fine if they are short enough. Which in our case solved the issue because our customer never had pdfs which were more than few pages.